# Multiple Kafka producers with different `ack`

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm wondering about some scenario. Let's assume we have Kafka cluster with 3 nodes (`97`, `98`, `99`), topic `A` with `replication.factor=3`, `min.insync.replicas=2` and `unclean.leader.election=false`. We started two producers: one with `ack=all` and second with `ack=1`. Both are continously sending messages to topic `A`. What happens when:

- t[0] broker `97` is partition leader
- t[1] producer `ack=all` sends message to leader, message gets offset `12`
- t[2] message `12` is replicated to broker `98` but it's not replicated to broker `99`
- t[3] producer receives acknowledgement
- t[4] brokers `97` and `98` goes down
- t[5] producer `ack=1` sends message

Is it possible that broker `99` will be elected as leader and in timestamp 6, producer receives acknowledgement?

If no - how Kafka knows that broker `99` cannot be elected as leader? Is it connected somehow with High Watermark?

If yes - what offset gets message sent in timetsamp 5? and what will happen when brokers `97` and `98` goes up afterwards?

Comment: 99 shouldn't become leader because you have minISR=2 and unclean leader election disabled, therefore, producer at t[5] should fail

Comment: Cool, I didn’t know that minISR is affecting leader election but it makes sense, thanks!